# Non separability implies $\sigma(W^*)$ not Borel

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am looking for a proof or counter example to the following:
Let $W$ be an inseparable banach space and $W^*$ be its topological dual; then $\sigma(W^*)\neq B(W)$ for $B(W)$ is the Borel sigma algebra.

In general we have: separable Banach $\Rightarrow \sigma(W^*)=B(W)$

Comment: The basic idea is this: every set in the sigma algebra generated by $W^{*}$ belongs to the sigma algebra generated by a countable number of elements of $W^{*}$: you can write the set as $\{x\in W: (x_1^{*}(x),x_2^{*}(x)...)\in A\}$ for some Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb R^{\infty}$. But $\{x:\|x\|<1\}$ cannot be written in this form if $W$ is not separable.

Comment: I can't tag on phone but I'd be very interested in a reference to a full proof